# How to switch to a second power source if the first loses power

Tags: power-supply, power

I am trying to wire two power sources to one led strip. I need a switch or relay to switch between each power supply depending on which one has power coming to it, then once the first power supply loses power it will automatically switch to the other?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care which one supplies the power when both are present, you can just use two diodes (assuming the sources are DC).

The one with the higher voltage supplies the current. You will get a small voltage drop in the diodes (Schottky diodes have a bit less drop typically).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frHTn9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diode rating must be adequate for the current, and the diode must be able to withstand the reverse voltage when one source is off. The type shown is adequate for a couple amperes at any realistic voltage.

Comment: By simply adding a diode to each current that should do the trick then?

Comment: Yes, if you don't care which one supplies the current (if one is a battery this may be a bad choice) and if your LED strip doesn't mind 0.7V or so of voltage drop. That easy.

Comment: Then the diode's will know whatever current is stronger will be able to pass through? Then once the stronger current drops it go back to the previous current?

Comment: It seems to simple haha! Thank you for your help Spehro!

Comment: Actually, which ever source has a higher **voltage** will be used.

Comment: What if they are both carrying the same voltage? 12v

Comment: In reality one voltage will probably be slightly higher (eg. 12.1 vs. 11.9) than the other and it will likely take the lion's share of the current (which will warm the respective diode and it will take even more). The currents will not share equally.

Comment: Well I will have to give this a try! Wish me luck, thank you for your help!

Comment: The method suggested consists of just tying the power supplies togheter to the load and making sure that there is protection.There is nothing wrong with that ,it's simple,but I really doubt such a design is eligible for sale as a good product.No?

Answer (score 0):

Primary power (dc or ac) could power a double pole double throw relay (dc or ac respectively). Primary power would be connected to N.Os.  Secondary power would be connected to N.Cs. The load would be connected to COMs. The neutrals or negatives could be connected together. When primary power is lost the relay turns off and connects secondary power. Primary will consume slightly more power because it would be powering the load and relay. However the secondary consumes no significant power. This is commonly used when primary is utility power and secondary is reserve (battery, generator, other). The advantages are that it can be for AC/DC and has no voltage drop like using diodes for DC. The biggest disadvantage is there is a short period when the relay switches to which there is no power to the load.

If this temporary power loss can be tolerated and powering a relay with primary power as well isn't an issue, then a relay may be the best choice.

[image: Relay based Automatic Transfer Switch (ATS)]

Comment: A drawing or schematic would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image: Simple circuit using a linear regulator to match the LED voltage. e.g. change 7805 for 7512 for 12 volts.]

Simple circuit using a linear regulator to match the LED voltage. e.g. change 7805 for 7512 for 12 volts.  These regulators handle currents under 1A but require heastsinks. The ground connection from the reg is not shown.

Comment: This assumes the power supply matches the voltage of the battery plus one diode drop.